# While running the robotframwork automation code from pycharm, .robot file is deleting automatic

Tags: python, robotframework

While running the robotframwork automation code from pycharm file is deleting automatic .

please refer the screenshot for more details.[image]

[image]

I tried running my script but while clicking on run command file is deleting automatic.
I am using Python 3.11.0

Comment: Are you reading or modifying that file inside your script?

Comment: modifying, same script was working 2 hours before and now not working.

Comment: Check that you are saving the file where you want it to be. This sounds like that when the script is saving the file, it changes location to somewhere else.